# Jumbotron div's overflowing

Tags: html, css, iframe, twitter-bootstrap-3, overflow

I'v been having a hard time trying to fix this. I want to display two iframes at full browser width and heigth. This is inside .jumbotron from Boostrap 3. 
The two iframes are a video and a chat ( I want to "mimic" a theathre mode ).

I have finally been able to align the stuff in the divs etc. But now I am facing this problem, the iframe and chat div's are overflowing the jumbotron.

If i set overflow:hidden to .jumbotron the video and chat are cut down, this blocks the video controls and chat send buttons.
Basically I need the iframes to adjust to the jumbotron and everything will be ok (100% width and heigth).

Should note that the iframes are both from a twitch.tv channel.

Thank you for your patience!

Heres the code:

```css
body {
  font-weight: 300;
}

.jumbotron {
  display: flex;
  align-items: center;
  background-size: cover;
  color: blue;
  text-shadow: 0.25px 0.25px 0.25px #000000;
  padding: 0px;
  padding-left: 0px;
  padding-right: 0px;
  height: 100vh;
  
}
.twitchWrapper {
 width: 100vw;
}

.twitchVideo {
 width: calc(100% - 300px);
 height: 100%;
}

.twitchChat {
 width: 300px; 
}

.nopadding {
   padding: 0 !important;
   margin: 0 !important;
}

.nomargin {
 margin: 0 !important;
 padding: 0 !important;
}
```

```html
<html>

<head>
<meta charset="utf-8" />
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.6/css/bootstrap.min.css"/>
<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="twitch.css">
</head>

<body>
<section class="jumbotron">
<div class="container nomargin">
<div class="row twitchWrapper">
<div class="twitchVideo embed-responsive embed-responsive-16by9 col-lg-9">
<iframe class="embed-responsive-item video" src="https://player.twitch.tv/?channel=lirik" frameborder="0" scrolling="no" ></iframe>
</div>
<div class="twitchChat embed-responsive embed-responsive-16by9 col-lg-3">
<iframe class="embed-responsive-item chat" src="https://www.twitch.tv/lirik/chat?popout=" frameborder="0" scrolling="no" ></iframe></div>
</div>
</div>
</section>
</body>

</html>
```

If I add overflow: hidden; to .jumbotron cant propperly control the stuff. https://snag.gy/UlewLH.jpg

Answer (score 0):

Just remove `height: 100vh` from `.jumbotron`

```css
body {
  font-weight: 300;
}

.jumbotron {
  display: flex;
  align-items: center;
  background-size: cover;
  color: blue;
  text-shadow: 0.25px 0.25px 0.25px #000000;
  padding: 0px;
  padding-left: 0px;
  padding-right: 0px;
  
}
.twitchWrapper {
 width: 100vw;
}

.twitchVideo {
 width: calc(100% - 300px);
 height: 100%;
}

.twitchChat {
 width: 300px; 
}

.nopadding {
   padding: 0 !important;
   margin: 0 !important;
}

.nomargin {
 margin: 0 !important;
 padding: 0 !important;
}
```

```html
<html>

<head>
<meta charset="utf-8" />
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.6/css/bootstrap.min.css"/>
<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="twitch.css">
</head>

<body>
<section class="jumbotron">
<div class="container nomargin">
<div class="row twitchWrapper">
<div class="twitchVideo embed-responsive embed-responsive-16by9 col-lg-9">
<iframe class="embed-responsive-item video" src="https://player.twitch.tv/?channel=lirik" frameborder="0" scrolling="no" ></iframe>
</div>
<div class="twitchChat embed-responsive embed-responsive-16by9 col-lg-3">
<iframe class="embed-responsive-item chat" src="https://www.twitch.tv/lirik/chat?popout=" frameborder="0" scrolling="no" ></iframe></div>
</div>
</div>
</section>
</body>

</html>
```

Hope this is what you asking for.

Comment: Yes and no, If I do that the content fits inside .jumbotron ; but then the video and chat exceed the window height. Im trying to "fullscreen" the content.

Thank you ;)

Comment: Okay, so you want to fit the chat and video in .jumbotron? is it okay to have scroll ?

Answer (score 0):

Try the below code, I hope this will work for you.

```css
.jumbotron{
 margin: 0px 0px 0px 0px;
 padding: 0px 0px 0px 0px;
}
.chat{
 height: 100vh;
}
.video{
 height: 100vh;
}
.nopadding{
    padding:0px;
}
```

```html
<link href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.6/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet" />
<section class="jumbotron">

<div class="col-sm-9 nopadding">
<!-- 16:9 aspect ratio -->
<div class="video embed-responsive embed-responsive-16by9">
  <iframe class="embed-responsive-item" src="https://player.twitch.tv/?channel=lirik"></iframe>
</div>
</div>

<div class="col-sm-3 nopadding">
<!-- 16:9 aspect ratio -->
<div class="chat embed-responsive embed-responsive-16by9">
  <iframe class="embed-responsive-item" src="https://www.twitch.tv/lirik/chat?popout="></iframe>
</div>
</div>

</section>

<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.6/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
```